# how to get file path in list?

Tags: python, list, file, filepath

I'm trying to learn python.

I would like to have a list of all files in all subdirectories and then pick one random file and open it (all files are different image types).

At the moment, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\pythonProject\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    os.startfile(d)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden: (file can not be found)
```

I guess it is because I only get the NAME of the file and not the path?

How could I list all file paths and then pick one at random?

Full code below:

```
import random
import os
from os import walk

# folder path
dir_path = "M:/01_Bilder/01_Shootings"

# list to store files name
AllFiles = []
for (dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in walk(dir_path):
    AllFiles.extend(file_names)
print(AllFiles)
d=random.choice(AllFiles)
print("file is " + d)
os.startfile(d)
```

I am new to python and got here with a tutorial, but I do not yet fully understand how python works. Please be patient.

Answer (score 2):

The third item that `os.walk` gives you only the names of files, not their entire path. `os.startfile` then searches for the filename in the directory you're running your script from.

You either have to also combine the path of the containing folder, the first item that `os.walk`gives you, with the filename:

```
# NOTE: To avoid name conflicts, I'd recomment changing the name
# of this variable to not crash into your initial path.
# Therefore, dir_path -> current_dir_path
for (current_dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in walk(dir_path):
    for file_name in file_names:
        AllFiles.append(os.path.join(current_dir_path, file_name))
```

Or you can use a tool that does that for you, i.e. `pathlib`, which gives you `Path`-objects with absolute paths included.

```
import pathlib

...
AllFiles = [file for file in pathlib.Path(dir_path).rglob("*") if file.is_file()]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work I changed the way of adding the files to the list 'ALLFiles':

```
import random
import os
from os import walk

# folder path
dir_path = "folder"

# list to store files name
AllFiles = []
for (dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in walk(dir_path):
    for file in file_names:
        AllFiles.append(dir_path + os.sep + file)
print(AllFiles)
d=random.choice(AllFiles)
print("file is " + d)
os.startfile(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using `pathlib`. It is a more modern interface for dealing with files that better deals with filesystem objects, including paths, filenames, permissions, etc..

```
>>> import random
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('/tmp/photos')
>>> files = [x for x in p.glob('**/*') if x.is_file()]
>>> random_file = random.choice(files)
>>> print(random_file)
/tmp/photos/photo_queue/KCCY2238.JPEG
```

It gives you easy ways to deal with lots of things you would want to do with files:

```
>>> file = files[0]
>>> file.name
'GYEP0506.JPG'
>>> file.stem
'GYEP0506'
>>> file.suffix
'.JPG'
>>> file.parent
PosixPath('/tmp/photos/photo_queue')
>>> file.parent.name
'photo_queue'
>>> file.parts
('/', 'tmp', 'photos', 'photo_queue', 'GYEP0506.JPG')
>>> file.exists()
True
>>> file.is_absolute()
True
>>> file.owner()
'daniel'
>>> file.with_stem('something_else')
PosixPath('/tmp/photos/photo_queue/something_else.JPG')
```